# Flex: application trying to access http://localhost/crossdomain.xml on server when no external domain has been specified

Tags: apache-flex

I have recently uploaded my flex applicaiton on server, it works fine on my system (localhost) but on the production server it tries to access http://localhost/crossdomain.xml which is not available and end up showing "loading" eternally.

Answer (score 2):

Check your code and see if anywhere you are referencing localhost url.Like,for instance you might be using a localhost url for a httpservice call.

Comment: To add to this, try not to use 'absolute' url paths, always use relative when possible, as in `<HTTPService url="someDir/someFile.txt" />`.  This way it doesn't matter which server you deploy to, it will always use the current location of the html file that's serving your Flex app as the basis.

Answer (score 1):

I have a flex client communicating with a zend-framework based server. Client and Server are hosted on different computers (also on the same development computer with different url). What I had to do to make it work is as follows:

I had to edit the file `\src\services\_Super_MyHttpService.as` in my flex client's source code and update http url from `http://localhost/` to `http://SERVER_IP/` for variable called `_serviceControl`. Then compile the flex client.

I also put `crossdomain.xml` file in the server's root directory with content like:

```
<?xml verspion="1.0">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="CLIENT_IP"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Note: replace `SERVER_IP`, `CLIENT_IP` with the correct IP address where the server and flex clients are hosted respectively.